# Virtualizing An App Without Installing It First

Tags: virtualization, vmware

What I understand from the documentations is that ThinApp first captures the current state of the computer (e.g. the registry etc) and captures the state after you install the application.

What I want is not installing the application directly on the target computer. I just want a virtual and portable version of it. The reasons are:

1. I do not want the application installed on my machine and that is
   why I am opting for virtualization in the first place.
2. Using a VM for each app virtualization might work I guess but it seems like an overkill.
3. I don't understand why ThinApp needs a diff of the pre and post states. Can't it just provide a dummy environment for the app to be installed on.

How can I do it? (Either with ThinApp if possible, or with any other app virtualization software)

Comment: "I don't understand why ThinApp needs a diff of the pre and post states" - This is the way ThinApp was designed.  "Can't it just provide a dummy environment for the app to be installed on."  - It was not designed to support this.

Comment: It sounds like you want Vagrant/Docker

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can if you already had the files the installer adds to your computer (which you don't), but even then you would need to script a custom package.ini pointing to said files. This also depends on what software you want to virtualize and what type of installer package you have. If the installer is protected, then no, you cannot. I used to use ThinApp for all of my portable software, and through my experience you cannot easily achieve your goal with ThinApp. As far as why you need a pre-system snapshot and post-system snapshot goes this is because ThinApp compares the differences then copies the according changes to the project folder to be bundled in the sandbox/virtual application. The pre-snapshot should be as sterile as possible with little to no traces of the target program. You do have a few other options though. I started virtualizing software with [Cameyo](http://www.cameyo.com/). It has a decent freeware version and was a good start because it is so user-friendly. And whats more, you can manually build a virtual application. Currently I use [Turbo Studio](https://turbo.net/studio), a bit pricey, but worth it. You can also manually build virtual applications with it. If you want, I specialize in software virtualization and could do it for you.

I just upgraded to [Turbo Studio 17](https://turbo.net/studio/download?download=studio) and they have implemented just what your looking for. The tools description is as follows: "New! Create applications by installing the application (MSI or EXE) into a container console. This alternative to the snapshot process does not require a clean operating system and does not dirty up the host filesystem or registry." Full documentation can be found [here](https://blog.turbo.net/turbo-studio-17-now-available/).

Comment: What aspects would make you recommend these in particular? Please see [how to recommend software](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330) for how best to suggest software in an answer.

Comment: It's. It possible to "private message" somebody so answers that offer that service are not helpful to the community.  If you cannot everyone with an answer then you should not submit an answer

Comment: SE isn't a traditional forum - feel free to edit for any updates rather posting a new answer. We don't have a private message system either. You may want to have a look at the [tour] and [help] for a better idea of how we do things